# Batch merge error - wrong data type money?

Tags: contacts, import, duplicate-contacts

I'm trying to clean up some duplicates using the batch merge tool, and it keeps showing this error:

[Error: Processed 2 pair of duplicates out of 9]
value: null is not of the right field data type: Money

Any ideas?

Here's the full debug:

```
[Error: Processed 28 pair of duplicates out of 77]
Exception: "value: null is not of the right field data type: Money"

#0 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/CustomValueTable.php(595): CRM_Core_Error::createAPIError("value: null is not of the right field data type: Money")
#1 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Dedupe/Merger.php(1777): CRM_Core_BAO_CustomValueTable::setValues((Array:10))
#2 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Dedupe/Merger.php(748): CRM_Dedupe_Merger::moveAllBelongings("434", "204616", (Array:21))
#3 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Dedupe/Merger.php(624): CRM_Dedupe_Merger::merge((Array:2), (Array:3), "safe", TRUE, TRUE)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/DedupeMerge.php(138): CRM_Dedupe_Merger::batchMerge("26", "263", "safe", TRUE, 2, 2)
#5 [internal function](): CRM_Contact_Page_DedupeMerge::callBatchMerge(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext), "26", "263", "safe", TRUE, 2, 2)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Task.php(88): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:7))
#7 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Runner.php(214): CRM_Queue_Task->run(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext))
#8 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php(52): CRM_Queue_Runner->runNext(TRUE)
#9 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/ErrorPolicy.php(106): CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::{closure}()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php(54): CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy->call(Object(Closure))
#11 [internal function](): CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::runNext()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(278): call_user_func((Array:2))
#13 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#14 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#15 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(454): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#16 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("queue", "ajax", "runNext")
#17 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:3))
#18 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#19 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create a bug report in JIRA referencing this question if it continues to occur when extensions like Summary Fields are disabled.

Comment: On further investigation, this bug is caused by the "Summary Fields" extension.  Not sure which end the bug lives on - the extension or the batch merge script - should I still file a real bug report?

Comment: If the bug goes away when the extension is disabled, file the bug against the extension. Normally extensions reside on github and maintainers turn on issues for theirrepos. Check for details in the info.xml file in top level directory of the extension for more details.